# Request contains an invalid argument Location paramter Youtube API

Tags: python, youtube-api

Hi all im trying to make a simple python script that will return all videos created in a certain year near a ceratin latiude and longiute within 1km radius. however im getting this error saying Request contains an invalid argument when i use location paramter in the query.Anybody know how to fix this?

Request contains an invalid argument.

```
import googleapiclient.discovery


api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"
DEVELOPER_KEY = 'key'
# API client

youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)

request = youtube.search().list(
        part="id,snippet",
        type='video',
        videoDuration='short',
        videoDefinition='high',
        publishedAfter='2012-07-05T11:10:04Z',
        publishedBefore='2013-07-05T11:10:04Z',
        location='37.42307,-122.08427',
        locationRadius='1km'

     
      
)


response = request.execute()


for item in response['items']:
    # Getting the id
    vidId = item['id']['videoId']
    # Getting stats of the video
    print("Publish date:",item ['snippet']['publishedAt'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Python library has a bug, maybe just retrieving JSON from:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&videoDuration=short&videoDefinition=high&publishedAfter=2012-07-05T11:10:04Z&publishedBefore=2013-07-05T11:10:04Z&location=37.42307,-122.08427&locationRadius=1km&key=API_KEY

would fit your needs, as this URL returns at least a correct result ([dKyngAFggRM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKyngAFggRM)).